# What is the most reliable way to move or copy large files (> 100 MB) on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems, nsfilemanager

Right now I'm moving very large files in iOS with this method:

```
[fileManager moveItemAtURL:srcURL toURL:toURL error:&error];
```

This is a method from NSFileManager.
Because the files are so large I try to move them instead of copying and then deleting the source file.

Is there a safer way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file move is an extremely light weight operation;  it doesn't involve copying anything as it simply moves a directory entry from one point in the filesystem to another.

It should be quite safe.

If you really *really* want to be paranoid, then:

- copy all bytes from A to B
- verify B is coherent
- delete A

Which is what the "atomically" variants for the write/copy APIs do under the covers, save for the verification part because the filesystem, itself, should do that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is correct and efficient. Moving a file (if to the same file system) is essentially instant. But a copy and delete is very slow. Please note that moving a file to a different file system is actually done with a copy and delete.